# Upload json object to Google Cloud Storage with Google Apps Script

Tags: json, google-apps-script, google-cloud-storage

I'm calling an API in a Google Apps Script. The response is a json object. I'd like to send it to Google Cloud Storage.

Here is the script I wrote so far:

```
function uploadToGoogleCloudStorage() {

  var api_response = '{ "var":"value"}'
  var url = 'https://storage.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/my_bucket_name/o/test?fields=OBJECT'.replace("OBJECT", JSON.stringify(api_response))

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
    method: "POST"
  });

}
```

I have the following error `Exception: Invalid argument: https://storage.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/gtm_container_export/o/test?fields="{%20\"var\":\"value\"}"`

I didn't find any documentation on how to interact with Google Cloud Storage from Google Apps Script. I'm wondering if `UrlFetchApp` is the right way to do it or if I should activate a specific service.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/how-to

Comment: This may help, also: [Uploading an object to a bucket](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects#rest-upload-objects)

Comment: There isn't any example on how things work with Google App Script in these documents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a basic example for you - your approach just needs to be modified a bit:

```js
function uploadToGoogleCloudStorage() {

  let url = "https://storage.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/[replace this with your bucket ID]/o?uploadType=media&name=my_test_json.json";

  let token = "Bearer [replace this with your oauth token!]";
 
  // this is the content of the document we will create in the bucket
  let data = {
    'name': 'Bob Smith',
    'age': 35,
    'pets': ['fido', 'fluffy']
  };

  let options = {
    'method' : 'post',
    'headers' : {
      'Authorization' : token
    },
    'contentType': 'application/json',
    // Convert the JavaScript object to a JSON string.
    'payload' : JSON.stringify(data)
  };
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);

  console.log( response.getResponseCode() ); // 200 OK
  console.log( response.getContentText() );

}
```

In this case, the file name in the bucket will be "my_test_json.json", as defined in `name=my_test_json.json`.

Replace `[replace this with your bucket ID]` with your bucket ID.

Replace `[replace this with your oauth token!]` with your oauth token.

If you are not familiar with tokens, that is a fairly large topic, and outside the scope of this question. But in case it helps, here are some very basic notes: To generate a test token, I used the [OAuth 2.0 Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground) to create a test token. I chose "Cloud Storage API" read/write scope. After step 2, I copy/pasted the `access_token` string out of the "response" box on the right had side of the page. This string is over 300 characters in length. This is not a production-strength solution - it's just for testing.

Comment: Thanks. That's the answer I was looking for. I was a bit lost because with Google App Script sometimes OAuth process is much more easier which doesn't seems the case with the Cloud Storage API. And the error msg I had was not clear about what was the issue really.